# Prevent next event handler being called

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

I have two event handlers wired up to a button click in a Windows form like so:

```
this.BtnCreate.Click += new System.EventHandler(new RdlcCreator().FirstHandler);
this.BtnCreate.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.BtnCreate_Click);
```

both are being called correctly.

However is it possible within `FirstHandler()` to prevent `BtnCreate_Click()` being executed? Something like:

```
void FirstHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (ConditionSatisfied)
     //Prevent next handler in sequence being executed

}
```

I know I could just unsubscribe the event, but can this be done programmatically (from within the method)?

Comment: why not just use a boolean flag?

Comment: ConditionSatisfied is mimicking one

Comment: Replace EventArgs by ChainEventArgs and add to it some variables that can suport your handlers chain logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no solution for this. That's because there is no guarantee for the order in which the event handlers are called when the event happens.

Because of  that you are not supposed to rely on their order in any way.

Comment: Handlers are called in the order in which they were attached, unless add/remove accessors are implemented in a weird way, on purpose. Why wouldn't they be called? They are stored in a plain list.

Comment: @Groo While it is actually true that all handlers are called in the order in which they were attached, it's an implemention detail you should not rely on.

Comment: I agree, ordering cannot be relied upon, I'll find a different method.

Comment: Implementation detail? According to MSDN: [invocation of a delegate instance (...) proceeds by invoking each of the methods in the invocation list, synchronously, **in order**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664605(v=vs.71).aspx). I would like to see a concrete example where someone has overridden the `add` accessor and *shuffled* the list to confuse their API users. If you want to be really paranoid, who can guarantee that my accessor doesn't look like this: `add { }`?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just replace them with one eventhandler? Something like this:

```
var rdlc = new RdlcCreator();
this.BtnCreate.Click += (sender, e) => {
    rdlc.FirstHandler(sender, e);
    if (!rdlc.HasHandledStuff) { // <-- You would need some kind of flag 
        this.BtnCreate_Click(sender, e);
    }
};
```

That way you can also guarantee the order of the handlers. Alternatively, use the above implementation, but change the signature of FirstHandler to return a bool indicating the condition (as in this case it doesn't really need to have the event's signature anymore):

```
    if (!rdlc.FirstHandler(sender, e)) { 
        this.BtnCreate_Click(sender, e);
    }
```

**EDIT**: OR, you just pass the second handler to FirstHandler.
Change the signature of FirstHandler to this:

```
void FirstHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, EventHandler nextHandler) {
    if (ConditionSatisfied) {
        // do stuff
    }
    else if (nextHandler != null) {
        nextHandler(sender, e);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
this.BtnCreate.Click += 
    (s, e) => new RdlcCreator().Firsthandler(s, e, this.BtnCreate_Click);
```

Answer (score 2):

`System.ComponentModel` namespace contains a [`CancelEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventhandler.aspx) delegate which is used for this purpose. One of the arguments it provides is a [`CancelEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs) instance which contains a boolean `Cancel` property which can be set be any of the handlers to signal that execution of the invocation list should be stopped.

However, to attach it to a plain `EventHandler` delegate, you will need to create your own wrapper, something like:

```
public static class CancellableEventChain
{
    public static EventHandler CreateFrom(params CancelEventHandler[] chain)
    {
        return (sender, dummy) =>
        {
            var args = new CancelEventArgs(false);
            foreach (var handler in chain)
            {
                handler(sender, args);
                if (args.Cancel)
                    break;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

For your example, you would use it like this:

```
this.BtnCreate.Click += CancellableEventChain.CreateFrom(
    new RdlcCreator().FirstHandler,
    this.BtnCreate_Click
    /* ... */
);
```

Of course, you would need to capture the created chain handler in a field if you need to unsubscribe (detach) it later.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following condition in this.BtnCreate_Click which is the the second event

```
BtnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{     
   if (!ConditionSatisfied)       //Prevent next handler in sequence being executed 
   {
     // your implementation goes here
   }   
}
```

Comment: You didn't get my point buddy. You are using this condition in CreateFrom EventHandler but I have put it in BtnCreate_Click eventhandler. The difference is that you don't need to unsubscribe the event. This the only orthodox way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a some kind of class wrapper. So, you could store there some kind of **event flag group** (16bit integer, for example) and a few methods to set or unset individual bits (where each means to invoke or not particular `EventHandler`). You can easily store any count of the `Eventhandlers` or even `Actions`, in the class, and invoke in any order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Was finding the solution to the same question, but no luck. So had to resolve myself.
A base class for Cancelable event args

```
public class CancelableEventArgs
{
    public bool Cancelled { get; set; }
    public void CancelFutherProcessing()
    {
        Cancelled = true;
    }
}
```

Next defines the extension method for the EventHandler, note that Invocation List subscribers invoked in backward order (in my case UI elements subscibe the event as they added to components, so which element is rendered later has most visiblility and more priority)

```
public static class CommonExtensions
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void SafeInvokeWithCancel<T>(this EventHandler<T> handler, object sender, T args) where T : CancelableEventArgs
    {
        if (handler != null)
        {
            foreach (var d in handler.GetInvocationList().Reverse())
            {
                d.DynamicInvoke(sender, args);
                if (args.Cancelled)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the usage

```
public class ChessboardEventArgs : CancelableEventArgs
{
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
}
```

So if an UI element has some behaviour on the event, it cancells futher processing

```
        game.OnMouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, a) =>
        {
            var xy = GetChessboardPositionByScreenPosition(a.XY);
            if (IsInside(xy))
            {
                var args = new ChessboardEventArgs { Position = xy };
                OnMouseDown.SafeInvokeWithCancel(this, args);
                a.CancelFutherProcessing();
            }
        };
```