# How to stop calling OnBackKeyPress method on pressing the hardware back key in wp8?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have this requirement where I need to show a custom popUp as a page overlay. This custom PopUp is random and can show up on any page (based on some logic). I have registered the `OnBackKeyPress` event (for the current page) in this custom PopUp class.

But because almost all the pages of app also has an `OnBackKeyPress` method defined (again as per business requirement), the new event registration (in the custom PopUp class) takes place after the previous one. So on pressing the hardware back key, the `OnBackKeyPress` method written in pages is getting called first followed by the `OnBackKeyPress` method written in custom PopUp class. I need to avoid calling `OnBackKeyPress` method written in pages.

**Solutions not acceptable** :

1. make the new popUp control as a `PhoneApplicationPage` (we need some transparency where we can show the current page's data)
2. Put check on `OnBackKeyPress` method on all pages for the popUp (so many pages in ap!)
3. Extend `PhoneApplicationPage` and write a new `OnBackKeyPress` method to handle the same (no no!)

Comment: Can't you simply detach/attach the page handler when the popup is shown/closed ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031548/prevent-next-event-handler-being-called

Comment: If what you want is to subscribe an event before already existing event handler, I can post a useful answer

Comment: @codroipo Yes I want to subscribe to an event before the already existing event handler and after the new event has been called, I want to subscribe to the older one again (the already existing event)

Comment: `almost all the pages of app also has an OnBackKeyPress method defined` unless each page has different logic for OnBackKeyPress, "unacceptable solution #3" was definitely the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to subscribe an event before already subscribed handlers:

```
class EventTesterClass // Simple class that raise an event
{
    public event EventHandler Func;

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        Func(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

static void subscribeEventBeforeOthers<InstanceType>(InstanceType instance, string eventName, EventHandler handler) // Magic method that unsubscribe subscribed methods, subscribe the new method and resubscribe previous methods
{
    Type instanceType = typeof(InstanceType);
    var eventInfo = instanceType.GetEvent(eventName);
    var eventFieldInfo = instanceType.GetField(eventInfo.Name,
                                        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                        BindingFlags.Instance |
                                        BindingFlags.GetField);

    var eventFieldValue = (System.Delegate)eventFieldInfo.GetValue(instance);
    var methods = eventFieldValue.GetInvocationList();

    foreach (var item in methods)
    {
        eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(instance, item);
    }
    eventInfo.AddEventHandler(instance, handler);
    foreach (var item in methods)
    {
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(instance, item);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var evntTest = new EventTesterClass();
    evntTest.Func += handler_Func;
    evntTest.Func += handler_Func1;
    evntTest.RaiseEvent();
    Console.WriteLine();
    subscribeEventBeforeOthers(evntTest, "Func", handler_Func2);
    evntTest.RaiseEvent();
}

static void handler_Func(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("handler_Func");
}

static void handler_Func1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("handler_Func1");
}

static void handler_Func2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("handler_Func2");
}
```

Output will be:

```
handler_Func
handler_Func1

handler_Func2
handler_Func
handler_Func1
```