# Prevent event from firing in derived form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a base form and a derived form. Suppose I have only one button on my base form and derived form also uses same button.

[image]

I want to prevent the button click event from firing on derived form if the condition is not satisfied on base form click event. Could you please help how can I achieve this? Here is my code:

[image]

Comment: I think most similar way is implement "bubbling up". Like keypress event but in a reversed way. Calling base first and check for the argument status.

Comment: You've subscribed *two* event handlers for Click, one in the base class and another in the derived class.  The one can't prevent the other from running.  You'll have to remove the event handler in the base class.  Or re-raise another event in the base class (one that uses, say, CancelEventArgs), that the derived one can subscribe.  Or call a protected virtual OnButtonClick method.  KISS is advisable.

Comment: [Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031548/prevent-next-event-handler-being-called).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a separate method that you mark as virtual then instead of adding an event handler to the derived form you just call the virtual method in the original form.

```
public Base : Form
{
    public button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoSomethingOnClick();
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomethingOnClick()
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Then in your derived form you can override DoSomethingOnClick to do what you need it to do:

```
public Derived : Base
{
    private bool SpecificCondition = false;

    protected override void DoSomethingOnClick()
    {
        if (SpecificCondition)
            base.DoSomethingOnClick();
        else
        {
            // Do something else here.
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is it means you only ever have one event handler for the click event so when it's clicked it calls DoSomethingOnClick() as this is a virtual method it can be overridden in the derived form and made to do something else. If you have a specific condition where you want the button click to only perform the base forms method then you can just call base.DoSomethingOnClick(), otherwise you insert your code to do something else.

This stops you having to worry about suppressing click events as there is only ever one.